# Need to call a JavaScript function with Radio button onclick in JSF

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

I have a JavaScript function defined in a file Common.js named showSearchAccount() which show a pop-up when called. I have also defined two radio buttons in a xhtml file as;

```
 <h:selectOneRadio value="#{userData.data}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Yes" itemLabel="Yes" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="No" itemLabel="No" />
 </h:selectOneRadio>
```

I need the pop-up to apper when i click on yes radio button, but if I put *onclick* or *onchnage* inside the 1st *selectItem* tag the popup is not appearing. If I put the *onclick* in *selectOneRadio* tag it is working, but it gets enabled for both i.e Yes and No.

I have tried this thing with plain html and it works like charm. But I need to it work with JSF. Could anyone please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can let the onclick event at `<h:selectOneRadio>` and then decide what popup will be shown in the javascript function. I tried the code below and it worked:

XHTML:

```
<h:form>
        <h:selectOneRadio onclick="showPopUp(this.value)">Select:
            <f:selectItem itemValue="y" itemLabel="Yes" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="n" itemLabel="No" />
        </h:selectOneRadio> 
    </h:form>
```

JS:

```
function showPopUp(type) {
    //console.log(type);
    switch( type) {
        case 'y' : alert('pop up y!');  <--- call your function here for pop A
                   break;
        case 'n' : alert('pop up n!');  <--- call your function here for pop B
                   break;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Adding a switch statement will affect that function. That function is used at various places and I don't need alert as popup. Dojo Dialog box is displayed.

Comment: Couldn't you create a specific function for this radio? The alert was just an example. Replace it for your Dodo Dialog call.